# Location of functions

Tags: bash, function

If I run the `declare` command it returns some functions

```
$ declare -F | grep 'f [^_]'
declare -f dequote
declare -f quote
declare -f quote_readline
```

However if I run this command it does not find any files with that function

```
grep -r dequote /etc ~
```

How can I find the files that define these functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the file name and line number of a function declaration in bash, use `shopt -s extdebug`:

```
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ declare -F quote
quote 143 /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

Answer (score -1):

They are part of [Bash-Completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/)

```
$ egrep '^(dequote|quote)'  /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion 
quote()
quote_readline()
dequote()
```

Comment: Although the statement is correct, it does not answer the question "How can I find the files that define these functions?".